# FirebaseAuth JAVA (Spring boot) verify token

Tags: java, spring, firebase, firebase-authentication

Grettings.
i'm implementing a Firebase auth for my mobile app with custom existing back-end (Spring Boot).
I'm successfully authenticating in facebook by using firebase in mobile app => want to store user info at my back-end's DB (not firebase).

Stuck to debug the token verification error.

Token verification - almost same as in google doc:

```
   try {
        FirebaseToken decodedToken = Tasks.await(
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(info.getToken()));
    } catch (ExecutionException | InterruptedException | IllegalArgumentException e) {
        logger.error(e.getMessage());
    }
```

getting an error: `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException`

and can't find out/debug what is causing it.

related - **firebase config:**

```
@Configuration
public class FirebaseConfig {

    private final static Logger logger = LogManager.getLogger(FirebaseConfig.class.getName());

    @Value("classpath:firebase_config.json")
    private Resource firebase_config;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() throws IOException {

        FileInputStream serviceAccount = new FileInputStream(firebase_config.getFile());

        FirebaseOptions options = new FirebaseOptions.Builder()
                .setCredential(FirebaseCredentials.fromCertificate(serviceAccount))
                .setDatabaseUrl("https://******-81233.firebaseio.com")
                .build();
        FirebaseApp.initializeApp(options);
        logger.info("Firebase init done");
    }
}
```

**UPDATE:**
added:

```
FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(info.getToken()).addOnFailureListener(e -> {
                    System.err.println("Error verifying token: " + e.getMessage());
                });
```

the error i getting is simply `null` which isn;t saying anything about it's origin.

Comment: Firstly, please add the whole traceback. You could either let the request fail with `Tasks.await(
                FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(info.getToken()));`, or explicitly print it with `FirebaseAuth.getInstance().verifyIdToken(info.getToken()).addOnFailureListener(Throwable::printStackTrace);`

Comment: Then ensure, that your token matches the format. You may look at the `com.google.api.client.json.webtoken.JsonWebSignature$Parser.parse` method (JsonWebSignature.java:599 in my sources) - it contains a precondition check and will fail with `IllegalArgumentException` with `null` message if the token does not contain a dot

Answer (score -2):

Build release APK version. Deploy and try again. The hashes will be different so that it might help.